# Quando Referencio mais de uma coluna usando FormulaR1C1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft, planilha

bom dia!

Estou com problemas ao referenciar mais de uma coluna no excel usando VBA, por exemplo:

faço uma seleção das colunas **Estoque!A:G** e crio a macro, e gera pra mim **Estoque!C[-6]:C**, não entendi como ele se porta quando migro para referenciação da FormulaR1C1.

alguém pode me auxiliar nessa questão?

desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você gravou a macro ou tá fazendo ela na mão? Como aconteceu de chegar no Estoque!C[-6]:C?

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de não estar muito bem detalhado e explicado qual é o problema e o que vc pretende, concluo o seguinte:

Me parece que vc gravou a macro e vc está usando *referências relativas*, especialmente indicado pelas chaves(*[]*), ou sejá, **Estoque!C[-6]:C** está pegando a coluna onde está a célula ativa (representada pelo **C** sozinho) até 6 colunas à esquerda da coluna da célula selecionada (representada pelo **C[-6]**). Outras formas de representar este mesmo intervalo com *R1C1* seria:

- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna A: **Estoque!C:C[6]**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna B: **Estoque!C[-1]:C[5]**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna C: **Estoque!C[-2]:C[4]**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna D: **Estoque!C[-3]:C[3]**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna R: **Estoque!C[-4]:C[2]**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna F: **Estoque!C[-5]:C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H1xC.jpg)**
- Se a célula ativa estiver na coluna G: **Estoque!C[-6]:C** (igual ao seu)
- Sem *referência relativa*: **Estoque!C1:C7** (pega da 1ª até a 7º coluna)

Note que ao usar números entre chaves (*[]*) no modelo *R1C1* vc diz que a selecão se expande à esquerda ou à direita (no caso de colunas) a partir de uma célula ativa.

Caso queira para de gravar com *referências relativas* e pegar o endereço absoluto dos intervalos gravados, desabilite o recurso na aba *Desenvolvedor* do Excel:

[image: Usar Refências Relativas]